# Issue in Freeswitch ASR with mod_unimrcp

Tags: javascript, lua, debian, freeswitch, unimrcp

While using mod_unimrcp in freeswitch (with license) in lua script, speech is detected but not matched correctly with grammar. It shows 001-no match,but actually it matches with grammar. While trying in javascript, grammar does not load and speech does not detect. How can I solve this? Exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after the argument list "

```
session.execute("play_and_detect_speech") data=(/thilip/welcome.wavdetect:unimrcp:uni2 {start-input-timers=false,no-input-timeout=5000,recognition-timeout=5000} file:// /usr/local/freeswitch/grammar/sr.gram language=en-US;y=1;n=2 "
```

this is the line

Comment: you add the missing `)` after the argument list?

Comment: if i close the argument it again shows SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (near: "

Comment: share your code.

Comment: session.execute("play_and_detect_speech") data=(/thilip/welcome.wavdetect:unimrcp:uni2 {start-input-timers=false,no-input-timeout=5000,recognition-timeout=5000} file:// /usr/local/freeswitch/grammar/sr.gram language=en-US;y=1;n=2 "   this is the line

Answer (score 0):

`session.execute("play_and_detect_speech")` is syntactically correct.

`data=(/thilip/welcome.wavdetect:unimrcp:uni2 {start-input-timers=false,no-input-timeout=5000,recognition-timeout=5000} file:// /usr/local/freeswitch/grammar/sr.gram language=en-US;y=1;n=2 "` is not.

The only way to turn this into valid Lua code is to assign a string to data.

`data="(/thilip/welcome.wavdetect:unimrcp:uni2 {start-input-timers=false,no-input-timeout=5000,recognition-timeout=5000} file:// /usr/local/freeswitch/grammar/sr.gram language=en-US;y=1;n=2 "`

You cannot have something like `data=(/thili...` and you cannot have a single double quote nor anyhting else of that stuff outside a string.

Comment: [ERR] mod_dptools.c:524 Usage: <file> detect:<engine> {param1=val1,param2=val2}<grammar>
2022-09-19 05:09:17.944858 98.23% [ERR] mod_lua.cpp:202 /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/names.lua:27: attempt to concatenate global 'xml' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/names.lua:27: in main chunk    bro this is the error i got while running lua script.

Comment: so i changed the line to session:execute("play_and_detect_speech",menu .. "detect:unimrcp {start-input-timers=false,no-input-timeout=" .. no_input_timeout .. ",recognition-timeout=" .. recognition_timeout .. "}" .. grammar)
here i got 001-no match error

Comment: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/ASR this is the link where i follow lua script pls do help to come out of this issue